# Cannot open pipe descriptors created by threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pipe

I just began to study the pipe method of python.
I tried to wrap the pipe descriptors into file object and read by line.

```
import os,time,threading

def child():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = ('Spam\n' ).encode()
        os.write(pipeout,msg)


def parent(): 
    while True:
        a = os.fdopen(pipein)
        line = a.readline()[:-1]
        print('Parent %d got [%s] at %s' % (os.getpid(),line,time.time()))

pipein,pipeout = os.pipe()

threading.Thread(target=child,args=()).start()

parent()
```

when I run the script, the results are following----the script just works in the first iteration and then shows the error messages

```
Parent 621 got [Spam] at 1376785841.4  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/miteji/pipe-thread.py", line 43, in <module>
    parent()
  File "/Users/miteji/pipe-thread.py", line 36, in parent
    line = a.readline()[:-1]
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py",         line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/miteji/pipe-thread.py", line 30, in child
     os.write(pipeout,msg)
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

However, when I changed

```
a = os.fdopen(pipein)
line = a.readline()[:-1]
```

to

```
line = os.read(pipein,32)
```

the scrips works fine.

So Why the "os.fdopen" method cannot be used? why the pipe is broken? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the placement of `os.fdopen` here:

```
def parent(): 
    while True:
        a = os.fdopen(pipein)
        line = a.readline()[:-1]
        print('Parent %d got [%s] at %s' % (os.getpid(),line,time.time()))
```

Each trip through the loop, you call `os.fdopen()` *again*, even if you did before.

The first time you do it, you did not do any earlier `os.fdopen()`, so all is well.  But the second time, this re-binds `a` to the new result, abandoning the earlier `os.fdopen()` value.

When the earlier value is abandoned, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.  CPython notices immediately (due to reference counting) and collects it.  This deletes the underlying object, which calls `os.fdclose()`.  That, in turn, closes the pipe.

To fix the immediate problem, then, make sure you only open the pipe once, outside the loop.